# Preserve line breaks while substituting anything except the first letter and punctuation marks

Tags: javascript

```js
jQuery("#memorize-form").submit(function(){    
    var text = jQuery("#n-text").val();
    var substitute_with = "_";
    const regex = /\B\w/g;
    var result = text.replaceAll(regex, substitute_with);

    jQuery("#result").html(result);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="memorize-form" action="" method="get">
<textarea id="n-text" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button  id="memorize-submit">Convert</button>
</form>

<span>Result: </span><span id="result"></span>
```

This code replaces all the letters except the first on with the underscore. The punctuation should be made intact.

The text is input by the user.

The problem with it is that the text contains a line break, the line break is not preserved. It should be preserved.

Try this:

> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
>
> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters.

P.S.: The result disappears from the screen. Why is this?

Comment: Replace `<span id="result"></span>` with `<pre id="result"></pre>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, just detect `\n` and replace it with `<br/>`

```
jQuery("#memorize-form").submit(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents form submit
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //prevents form submit
    var text = jQuery("#n-text").val();
    var substitute_with = "_";
    const regex = /\B\w/g;
    var result = text.replaceAll(regex, substitute_with);
  
    //recommended way
    if(result.match(/[^\r\n]+/g)){ //check for \n and replace it with <br>
       result = result.replaceAll('\n','<br/>');
       //result = result.replace('\r','<br/>'); handle \r if needed
    }else{ 
        //not recommended way
        //check for  . `fullstops` and add a br. 
        //if(result.includes('.')){
        //  result = result.replace('.','<br/>');
        //}
    }
  
    jQuery("#result").html(result);
    
});
```

Tested code!